# View Content of Deleted File Svn

Tags: svn, command-line

For a deleted file what's the command to use to view the content of a old revision

```
E:\Downloads\eeli\eel\eel>svn cat eel-scalable-font.h -r 2
svn: warning: 'eel-scalable-font.h' is not under version control
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use a repository URL (not working copy), and use the @rev syntax. Something like:

```
svn cat https://myhost/svn/eeli/eel/eel/eel-scalable-font.h@2
```

Comment: And, if you don't know the last existing version of the file, you can look for it in the log. Something like this:  

    svn log -l 500 -v | grep -C 10 eel-scalable-font.h

Answer (score 3):

I think what your looking for is:

```
svn cat eel-scalable-font.h@2
```

Comment: no luck

E:\Downloads\eeli\eel\eel>svn cat eel-scalable-font.h@2 svn: warning: 'eel-scalable-font.h' is not under version control

But I can view the same in tortoise svn

Comment: This worked for me. Just instead of @2, I put @56374, which was the revision just before the file was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

ok got it.
I hve got to point to the repository rather than the working copy

E:\Downloads\eeld>svn cat file:///E:/Downloads/eel/trunk/eel/eel-scalable-font.h@2