# View content of deleted file in Synchronize view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

**System**
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers --
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) -- 
Build id: 20150924-1200

*Plugins*

- SVNKit Client Adapter -- 1.8.9
- SVNKit Library -- 1.8.12.r10533_v20160129_0158
- Subversion Revision Graph -- 1.1.1
- Subclipse -- 1.10.13
- Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x -- 3.0.0
- CollabNet Merge Client -- 4.1.0

**Scenario 1**
When I make changes in a file, I can go to the Synchronize view in Eclipse and watch a comparison between the old version and the changed version.

However, when I delete* a file and want to see the content of the file, I get a blank view of the file.

* When I say 'delete,' I mean that I delete it in the file system, i.e., by pressing <kbd>delete</kbd> on the given file.

**Scenario 2**
I am refactoring my code. 
I realize that a class has two responsibilities so I split it into two new classes with names different from the old class.
Now SVN considers the old class deleted. 
If I want to see whether I forgot something, I would go to the Synchronize view and see the content of the old class, but it is no longer available.

**Question**
How can I see the content of the going-to-be-deleted file in the Synchronize view in Eclipse?

**Duplication disclaimer** All found posts about deleted files in SVN are about how to avoid conflicts, generally use SVN, or this command-line approach: [View Content of Deleted File Svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300911/view-content-of-deleted-file-svn)

Comment: You've deleted the file. What is it you want it to show you?

Comment: The content of the file from the SVN repository.
I tried to make a simple scenario as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve but I've updated my question with a new scenario to hopefully clarify my needs.

Comment: Which SVN plug-in for Eclipse is involved?

Comment: I have updated my question with plugin information.
I got the information by going to `Help->Installation Details->Installed Software`.
I included everything that matched the search of `svn` and `subversion`.